# Syncing JSON-files with MongoDB collection

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB, but I've managed to use mongoimport to load some external JSON-files into my collection. My question is if there's a way to synchronize my mongo database collection with a folder of JSON-files? I'm looking for something like rsync, but for MongoDB.

Is there such a solution? Is this the best practice for syncing data with a Mongo database?

Answer (score 0):

watch the folder with nodejs and sync mongodb when add/remove and modify the json file